# Azure Event grid with service bus - The attempt to validate the provided endpoint failed

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-eventgrid

I'm new to Azure. For our use case, we decided to work with Azure Service Bus in conjunction with Event Grid in order to receive messages.

I followed the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept#azure-portal-instructions to connection function and namespace via Event Grid. While creating event subscription, I got error code - `ResourceDeploymentFailure`. The attempt to validate the provided endpoint failed. `Code:validation`.

What am I missing? I tried with javascript and java webhook functions. Does the function need to return validation code while creating a subscription with function URL?

TIA

Comment: The key scenario of this feature is that Service Bus queues or subscriptions with a low volume of messages do not need to have a receiver that polls for messages continuously. Is it your case ?

Comment: You are right. That's the case.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out, realized that it does need to return code while creating event grid subscription.